# How to organize a form with many fields?

Tags: forms, layout

Where I work, we have a system that has a screen with several fields. There are approximately 50 fields and all are important and should appear.

[image: example of a screen with about 50 fields]

//edited in gimp :D

Any suggestions on how to arrange the fields so that it does not look so ugly and complicated?

Comment: Could you post an English version of this form?

Comment: sure, give me a minute

Comment: Is it completely necessary to display all of these fields on the same screen? It seems like there're a few separate sections here that all deal with different information (contact info, vehicle, contract, etc.), so it might be possible to break up the workflow a bit (as much as I loathe wizards). Also, are there instances where you could auto-fill data (e.g. they provide Zip code, you fill in City/State?)

Comment: All fields are required

Comment: this is a good idea (eg They Provide Zip code, you fill in City / State?)

Comment: If all fields are required, why are only some marked with an asterisk?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the question's sake, let's assume all the fields are necessary. But **it could be a problem of Information Architecture.** Adressing it first could reduce the ammount of fields in the form and make it easier. [Here is a good article on IA and web forms](http://www.asis.org/Bulletin/Aug-08/AugSep08_Wroblewski.html).

The most obvious "problem" with the form is the **lack of rhythm and balance**, in fact it is breaking most of the known [design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_elements_and_principles#Principles_of_Design).

Notice how there are too many [vertical lines](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP8nnCqK4gE). This could be fixed by [using a grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_%28page_layout%29), and even [composing to a vertical rhythm](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm), it would give order to the form.

[image]

Last but not least, you could **make it into a multiple step form, so not all the fields are displayed at once.** [Here a Q&A explaining when to use each](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/261/multi-step-form-vs-single-complex-form) and [here on how to indicate progress.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/how-do-you-indicate-progress-to-users-in-a-multi-step-form)

Comment: I should've just posted my comment as an answer T_T :P

Comment: More than a little doubt that I discovered: it would be a bad idea to put the first step of the wizard applet for uploading files? When you click next, it will do the OCR file, which can be time consuming, and has sent to the server, so when the User conclude the registration, it would be faster to save. Part of uploading files had to be done with applets because it uses digital assinatura, and the rest of the register would be done in GWT,

Comment: A tabbed interface would make the sections of this form easier to read and complete.

Comment: Awkward form alignment makes baby jesus cry

Comment: This is one of the ugliest windows I ever seen. My eyes bleeeeed...

Comment: I...I don't even see the misaligned form. All I see is blonde, brunette, red-head.

Comment: @Xosler, depending on how you do the upload, you could fire the it in background thread and proceed with the rest of the form while the upload is ongoing in the background.

Comment: I'm not trying to be over-critical of your answer, because I think the advise is wise; but I do feel that references you've linked to are all just on the edge of being too abstract to be useful. The fact is that there are times where long forms with various different sized fields are necessary, and I'd love to see some actual screenshots on how to implement a form like this - because a lot of the good advice in the links just isn't practical sometimes, and that doesn't ever seem to get addressed.

Comment: @overslacked Mainly the links are about how to *visually organize* content (design principles, grids, multi-step form). They are not abstract, they are general, I wouldn't go into detail as of how to organize *this* particular form. (Don't mind the easter egg link.)

Answer (score 5):

Using tabs instead of groups and placing all the input fields in one constant-sized column would make it a lot easier on the eyes.

If you have comboboxes with less than about 5-7 possible items in them, replace them with listboxes - takes up more vertical space, but looks a lot better and if you use tabs you will have more space.

Comment: The problem with tabs it's that it doesn't convey a workflow. You need to expresselly indicate that there is a before and a next: multiple steps form. See this Q: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/how-do-you-indicate-progress-to-users-in-a-multi-step-form

Comment: Tabs could be a reasonable option if there is just one form that _must_ be filled and rest of the tabs would be optional. Otherwise it's pretty bas as Naoise Golden said it does not convey a workflow.

Comment: Tabs can easily be used as pages with prev, next buttons.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I think sequential form would be the effective solution for this problem. 
- It will force user to go through each step to complete process.
- No mandatory steps would be missed. (Its problem in tab that we cant see under which tab we have mandatory fields so we have to go through each and every tab)
- It reduces users cognitive load by dividing/splitting data.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

Use tabs for fields that aren't required.

Split the fields up (eg. Personal, financial, Accounting) into seperate appropriate tabs.

Find out what information people normally should fill in, if they fill in all of your form, that's not really UX, because that really are a lot of fields. If you are using this in a commercial application, users are going to think it's to crowded and to difficult, leading to more support calls, ... Perhaps you should look into it with your boss, what information can be automated / deleted. If i'm not mistaking, this is a legal document or a contract. If it's a contract, clients with address, name, number, ... / products with their tax and info should already be in the system, this would make the information overflow some easier to bear ;)

You also have derived fields, eg. when users fill in a city you can get the post/zip-code, region and country. When they fill in the streets, you know all of the previous (or can make a selection based on that), just saying.
Splitting in a wizard is one way to address it.

I normally have tabs with the first tab = "global" with all required fields.
Then i seperate tabs for their use and their usage (= used a lot - yes / no?).